# How to properly call methods returning future in Reactor

Tags: project-reactor

To prevent the XY problem, I'll start from the beginning:
I have a non-blocking SOAP client which I wrapped it to make the return type `Mono<T>` (By default it accepts callback. I can elaborate on this if needed).

Now I want to do (given ID):
1. Get the code by ID
2. Do something with the code
3. After that, get `Foo` and `Bar` and create `FooBar`
What I wrote was:

```java
public class MyService {

    private final MySoapClient soapClient;

    public Mono<FooBarDto> doSomething(String id) {
        return Mono.just(id)
                .flatMap(soapClient::getCode) // returns Mono<String>
                .flatMap(code ->
                        soapClient.doSomething(code) // returns Mono<Void>
                                .then(getFooBar(id, code))); // See this
    }

    private Mono<FooBarDto> getFooBar(String id, String code) {
        return Mono.zip(
                soapClient.getFoo(code), // returns Mono<Foo>
                soapClient.getBar(code) // returns Mono<Bar>
        ).map(tuple2 -> toFooBarDto(id, tuple2));
    }

    private FooBarDto toFooBarDto(String id, Tuple2<Foo, Bar> tuple2) {
        return FooBarDto.builder()/* set properties */.build();
    }

}
```

Now the problem is, because methods of the SOAP client are not lazy (the moment you call them they start the process), the semantic of `then` won't work here. Meaning I want to get `Foo` and `Bar` when `doSomething` is done. They all start together.
I tried to change it fix it by changing `then` to `flatMap`, but made it even worse. The `getFooBar` never got called. (1. Can someone please explain why?).

So what I ended up doing was to wrap SOAP calls again to make them lazy:

```java
public class MySoapClient {
    private final AutoGeneratedSoapClient client;

    Mono<Foo> getFoo(GetFooRequest request) {
        return Mono.just(request).flatMap(this::doGetMsisdnByIccid);
    }

    private Mono<Foo> doGetFoo(GetFooRequest request) {
        val handler = new AsyncHandler<GetFooRequest>();
        client.getFoo(request, handler);
        return Mono.fromFuture(handler.future);
    }

    private static class AsyncHandler<T> implements javax.xml.ws.AsyncHandler<T> {
        private final CompletableFuture<T> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

        @Override
        public void handleResponse(Response<T> res) {
            try {
                future.complete(res.get());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                future.completeExceptionally(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to do it? Specifically:
2. Using `CompeletableFuture` and the callback.
3. Making methods lazy in the SOAP client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to change it fix it by changing then to flatMap, but made it
>   even worse. The getFooBar never got called. (1. Can someone please
>   explain why?)

I think a `Mono<Void>` always completes empty (or error), so subsequent flatMap is never called.

> 2. Using CompeletableFuture and the callback.
> 3. Making methods lazy in the SOAP client.

To make the call lazy you can do one of the followings:

**1, You can use [`Mono.fromFuture`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#fromFuture-java.util.function.Supplier-) which accepts a supplier:**

```java
private Mono<Foo> doGetFoo(GetFooRequest request) {
    return Mono.fromFuture(() -> {
        val handler = new AsyncHandler<GetFooRequest>();
        client.getFoo(request, handler);
        return handler.future;
    });
}
```

**2, You can use [`Mono.defer`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#defer-java.util.function.Supplier-):**

```java
private Mono<Foo> doGetFoo(GetFooRequest request) {
    return Mono.defer(() -> {
        val handler = new AsyncHandler<GetFooRequest>();
        client.getFoo(request, handler);
        return Mono.fromFuture(handler.future);
    });
}
```

**3, You can get rid of CompletableFuture and use [`Mono.create`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#create-java.util.function.Consumer-) instead, something like this:**

```java
private Mono<Foo> doGetFoo(GetFooRequest request) {
    return Mono.create(sink -> {
        AsyncHandler<Foo> handler = response ->
        {
            try
            {
                sink.success(response.get());
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                sink.error(e);
            }
        };

        client.getFoo(request, handler);
    });
}
```

If you do any of these it will be safe to use `then` method and it will work as expected.